# oAuth2RestTemplate.exchange function returns 400 error response as the endpoint server doesn't send response within specific time

Tags: spring-mvc, oauth2resttemplate

When i make call to endpoint url, as the response from endpoint application takes more time, it gives 400 error response.How to increase the wait time in STS to receive the correct response from endpoint.Is there any configuration that increases the wait time to get the correct response from endpoint.

ResponseEntity restResponse = oAuth2RestTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

This issue occurs only to contracts having larger data, whereas works fine for smaller contracts.The endpoint takes time to process larger contract and send response.So ideally i need to make sure i wait for almost 1 min to get the response from endpoint system.